# Translation of "to be aware / conscious of something"

Tags: перевод, выражения

How to translate

1. ***to be aware / conscious of something***?
2. ***to become aware of something***?
3. ***to make aware of something***?

I thought of *сознаться* and *кому-то сознательный*, but I'm uncertain about it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your guess is wrong in this case.

If you are aware of something → it is *known* to you:

- Мне это **известно**
- Я это **осознаю** (понимаю).

Also "отдавать себе отчёт": "Я отдаю себе отчёт, что найти такую же
   работу будет непросто" ("I am well aware that...")

If you became aware of something, it became known to you →

- Мне **стало известно**
- Я **осознал, понял**

"make aware"... if you mean "let someone know something", it is

- **дать знать** + *Dat.*
- **поставить в известность** + *Acc.*.
- and **передать"/"рассказать** + *Dat.* are also possible

"сознаться" is actually "to confess".

Comment: How is it with things you know, but still its not so conscious to you (not sure myself here) e. g. many smokers *know* that smoking is harmful but still they are not *aware* of the damage they inflict to themselves an to others (just an example).

Comment: "осознавать" some fact works well for that or "отдавать себе отчёт". Also you may just use "понимать" (understand).

Answer (score 2):

One additional option for #1 *to be aware of something*:

`быть в курсе (чего-либо)` = to be up-to-date/informed about something.

I often heard "Он в курсе дела" - He is aware of the situation.